# Dynamic number of loops

Tags: python, loops, dynamic

I receive a string as input, of the form below:

```
x = "f(a,b) * g(b,c)"
```

the corresponding numerical expression `f[a][b] * g[b][c]` then should be summed over all `a` from `0` to `2`, `b` from `0` to `7`, `c` from `0` to `2`.

With this, I want to rewrite the code essence below, such that the loops (and the numerical expression being summed) adjust based on the string `x`.

So, with the current `x`, the 'hard-coded' looping could be:

```
t = 0
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(8):
        for c in range(3):
            t += <<insert numerical equivalent of the 
             ... f(a,b) * g(b,c) x string here, namely f[a][b] * g[b][c]>>

print t
```

If a new `x`, e.g.

```
x = "f(a,b) * g(b,c) * g(d,c)"`
```

is given, a new hard-coded loop would be required, to now run `a` from `0` to `2`, `b` from `0` to `7`, `c` from `0` to `2` and `d` from `0` to `7`, and sum the expression `f[a][b] * g[b][c] * g[d][c]`?

I have the logic to build a dictionary of loop variables and their respective number of values, based on the string input `x`, (`{'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 3}` for the original `x` and `{'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 3, 'd': 8}` for the new `x` - letters that appear as the second argument to `f` or first argument to `g` sum over values `0` to `7`, other letters sum from `0` to `2`).

`f` and `g` are given arrays of numbers. How can I have a generic piece of code that allows me to perform this summation dynamically (i.e. one piece of code that works for different `x`)?

## Let me restate the issue with a (hopefully more explanatory) code piece:

```
def dyn_sum(s):

    long_index = l_index(s) # returns a string of all 2nd args of f's and 1st args of g's

    short_index = s_index(s) # returns a string of all 1st args of f's and 2nd args of g's

    d_long_index = "".join(set(long_index))

    d_short_index = "".join(set(short_index))

    s_index = ({})

    for i in d_long_index: 

        s_index.update({i: 8})

    for i in d_short_index:

        s_index.update({i: 3})

    t = 1

    for i in range(len(s_index)):

        for j in range(s.values()[i]):

            t *= <<numerical form of the input string s goes here>>

return t
```

## It's that last piece that I struggle with: the input string s can contain any product of f and g:

for example: "f(a,b) * g(b,c)" or "f(a,b) * g(b,c) * g(d,c)", "g(a,b) * f(e,a) * g(d,e) * f(e,d)", etc. f and g are two 3x7 and 7x3 arrays of numbers, resp. The code must sum the corresponding numerical expression f[a][b] * g[b][c], or f[a][b] * g[b][c] * g[d][c], or g[a][b] * f[e][a] * g[d][e] * f[e][d], and the summations are 0 ... 7 for indices that appear as the second argument of b and/or first argument of f, and 0 ... 2 for others.

Is this a better (clearer) representation of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It's hard to extract a question from that, but one answer for a dynamic number of loops is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: i tried to format the post it a little better. the problem i can't figure out is: how do I specify the indices for the f, g arrays in expression I want to sum based on the loop variables?

Comment: Note that you can replace your current snippet with `for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(3), range(8), range(3)):` and take it from there.

Comment: here's what my code looks like:

Comment: Whitespace is important in Python code. How on earth do you expect people to read it in a comment? Please **edit the question** to provide the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be extended to *arbitrarily* long chains. The ranges should be apparent, you simply pass in a dictionary of the function mappings and the values you want to evaluate all the terms of the outer product over.

```
import itertools 

def f(x,y): return x+y
def g(x,y): return 2*x-y

def outer_product_thing(F,M):
    keys = M.keys()
    ranges = [M[k] for k in keys]

    for rx in itertools.product(*ranges):
        mapping = dict(zip(keys, rx))
        value   = 1

        for func in F:
            terms =   F[func]
            value *=  func(mapping[terms[0]], 
                           mapping[terms[1]])

        print "Evaluated: ", mapping
        yield value


F = {f:("a","b"), 
     g:("b","c")}
M = {"a":range(0,2),
     "b":range(0,3),
     "c":range(0,7)}

for result in outer_product_thing(F,M):
    print result
```

Output (truncated for space):

```
...
Evaluated:  {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 0}
0
Evaluated:  {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 1}
4
Evaluated:  {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
12
Evaluated:  {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}
-1
Evaluated:  {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}
...
```

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting, and thx to both @jonrsharpe and @Hooked! Very helpful to a newbie like me!